# How can I stop the AI great prophet from running around my cities forever? (Civ5)

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Let's say I have two cities with one inquisitor and one unit blocking the road between the cities. In theory, if the two cities are far apart enough, the AI great prophet shouldn't be able to convert either city because it has to leave the road at some point and that's when I move my inquisitor from one city to the other. However, the AI doesn't seem to realize this and the great prophet never gives up and keeps running around my two cities forever (until I slip up). Is there a way to stop this behavior besides DoW? It's a little annoying to have to deal with the great prophet every turn until endgame. I know that the great prophet will leave if I have an inquisitor in every city but I think that seems a little excessive.

Also, in general, the great prophet seems to know which of my cities have inquisitors stationed (pre-spy). The unit itself has a very limited sight range. Is this a bug or is it an intended map hack?